# Gerar valores e datas das parcelas em um datatable c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, matemática, devexpress

Olá,

Tenho um form onde é colocado um Valor Total da Venda, o Número de Parcelas do Pagamento. Aí gostaria de que o meu DataTable que está localizado no outro Form apresentasse os valores e as datas do vencimento com o seu valor dividido pela quantidade de meses.

Por exemplo:

```
       Valor Total: 200

       Prazo: 3
```

No datatable tem que aparecer:

---

```
 parcela    |  valor  | Data Vencimento
    01      |  66,67  |   02/02/2018
    02      |  66,67  |   02/03/2018
    03      |  66,67  |   02/04/2018
```

Deu pra entender a minha dúvida?
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida específica? o calculo?

Comment: Geração do cálculo e data do vencimento para cada parcela...
Quero que a saída venha ser igual do exemplo mostrado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segue um exemplo de demonstração.

```
decimal valorTotal = 200.00M;
int numeroParcelas = 3;
DateTime dataPrimeiroVencimento = DateTime.Now;

decimal valorParcela = Math.Round(valorTotal / numeroParcelas, 2);
decimal valorDiferenca = valorTotal - valorParcela * numeroParcelas;    

for (int i = 0; i < numeroParcelas; i++)
{

    //Calculo dos valores;
    string parcela = (i + 1).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
    string valor = !(i + 1 == numeroParcelas) ? valorParcela.ToString() : (valorParcela + valorDiferenca).ToString();
    string dataVencimento = dataPrimeiroVencimento.AddMonths(i).ToShortDateString();


    //Exemplo do resultado
    Console.WriteLine(parcela + " | " + valor + " | " + dataVencimento);
}
```

**Saída:**

```
01 | 66,67 | 02/02/2018
02 | 66,67 | 02/03/2018
03 | 66,66 | 02/04/2018
```

Comment: Não se esqueça de tratar a diferença entre o valor total e a soma total das parcelas. Como é o caso de R$ 100,00 / 3. O 0,01 centavo restante deve ser acrescentando na parcela final ou inicial.

Comment: Exato, bem colocado @LucasdeSouzaCruz, vou até adicionar o tratamento na resposta